# Printer Indicator missing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: printing, 14.04

Since updating to Ubuntu 14.04 when I print a document the Printer indicator doesn't show in the top toolbar.

How do I get it back?

Comment: Can you confirm "indicator-printers" in installed? (see USC)

Comment: I have same issue. and *'indicator-printers'* is installed (and newest version).

Comment: Yes I can confirm it's installed.

Comment: I've loaded Ubuntu 14.04 off a liveCD and I can confirm the same problem is happening while using the LiveCD. So either someone has removed it from Ubuntu 14.04 or it is not setup correctly. Can any one confirm that they have it working in their 14.04?

Comment: Peter - is this your bug report? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/1304434

Comment: Hi Fossfreedom - No that's not my bug report.

Comment: hmm - can you explain? - that bug report has exactly the same issue - no printer notification in 14.04

Comment: I thought you asked if I'd filed that bug report. That bug does sound exactly like what I have happening on my system. But it was in the beta version of 14.04. You would have thought as it was highlighted in the beta it would have been sorted by the live stage?

Comment: no - there is no guarantee that a beta issue would be resolved by live - bugs can and probably will be resolved as time permits during the next few days/weeks/months

Comment: ok - what I'll do is return your bounty to you.  Please subscribe to the bug-report to receive updates.  Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an HP printer then why not install HPLIP-GUI from the software centre and use that instead as it gives you a LOT more information about your printer including ink levels and cleaning/maintenance/alignment setup as well as an icon in your system tray...

Comment: This does not display the print queue immediately. I've had problems in the past install the GUI for HPLIP as there is a problem in the build of this package from HP and it doesn't install the postscript files correctly and it causes problems in Libreoffice not holding the printer settings for duplex printing - so I will not be installing the GUI - but thank you for suggesting it. But it does not resolve the issue with Ubuntu 14.04 not displaying the in-built print queue system tray icon.